# Google App Script dynamically defined custom functions

Tags: google-apps-script, dynamically-generated

How can I dynamically define custom function for spreadsheet from `onOpen()` function code?

- write a code...

```js
function onOpen() {
  //var s = SoapService.wsdl("http://example.com/service.wsdl", "serv");
  //var funcs = s.getServerFunctions();
  var funcs = { "pow2": "function (v) { return v*v};" }
  for(var f in funcs)
  {
     this[f] = eval(funcs[f]) // define server functions as custom google-script functions for spreadsheet using this[function_name] = eval(function_code)
  }
}
```

- try to call `=pow2()` ("pow2" is a function name) from any cell
- get an error "#NAME" - undefined function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GAS does not support dynamic functions calls from spreadsheets. As I wrote in my comment to the @Srik answer, a solution is to use a "static" dispatcher function which has 1st parameter the dynamic function name and starting from 2nd parameter are parameters of the dynamic function. In spreadsheet it will look like `=callFunction("pow2", 3)` or `=callFunction("mul", 3, 1)`.

But there is another problem. It seems that the GAS internals instance the script every call of the script functions, which means, that dynamic function created in the `onOpen` function will be not visible in the other functions. The following code demonstrates it. A cell containing the `=pow2static(3)` contains the `error: ReferenceError: "pow2" is not defined. (line XX)` error text.

A workaround is to download dynamic functions source code in the `onOpen` function, store it in an intermediate storage - either [Cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_cacheservice) or [ScriptDB](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_scriptdb) or better a combination `Cache` + `ScriptDB`, search the code by the name in the intermediate storage and execute it inside of the "static" dispatch function.

```js
function onOpen() {
  var funcs = { "pow2": "function (v) { return v*v};" }
  for(var f in funcs) {
    this[f] = eval(funcs[f]);
  }
}

function pow2static(val) {
  return pow2(val);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! Looks like you are right... and this is sad. Don't you know - is there any ErrorHandler which could catch and override "undefined functions" call?

Comment: Yes, an instance, containing the `ReferenceError: "myFunction" is not defined` text, of the standard ReferenceError class is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You don't require the onOpen at all. Just write your pow2() function and call it from any spreadsheet as

```
=pow2()
```

The formulas will anyway be recalculated each time you reopen your spreadsheet. Your pow2 function can look something like

```
function pow2(val){
  var ret = parseInt(val) * parseInt(val); 
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: The author's idea is "hidden" in the commented lines - `//var s = SoapService.wsdl("http://example.com/service.wsdl", "serv");
  //var funcs = s.getServerFunctions();`, i.e. he wants to donwload formulas dynamically using the SOAP protocol. IMHO a solution is to use a "static" function which has 1st parameter the dynamic function name and starting from 2nd parameter are parameters of the dynamic function. In spreadsheet it will look like `=callFunction("pow2", 3)` or `=callFunction("mul", 3, 1)`